# Use Token in contact form as default value

Tags: 8, tokens, emails

I have a contact form build from the drupal core contact forms.

I am trying to prefill some fields from URL GET parameters like this. `/?foo=bar` But it seems that "default value" doesnt support tokens.

I want to use something like this: `[current-page:url:args:value:foo]` in the default field of my form field.

But this gets just rendered as plain text.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Working solution with form_alter:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $args = \Drupal::request()->query->all();
  $form['field_test']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $args['foo'];
}
```

Maybe there is a solution with tokens relating to the topic?

Comment: Can you show more code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done in hook_form_contact_site_form_alter, like this:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_contact_site_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
      $args = \Drupal::request()->query->all();
      $form['subject']['#default_value'] = $args['foo'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I thought I could make some approach with tokens. But your solution worked for me with some modifications. I will update my question